# XFGloss: How to define as global style in App.xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to each content page contain the following element

```
<xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
        <xfg:Gradient Rotation="170">
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#9DCC5F" StepPercentage="0" />
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#00B0CD" StepPercentage="1" />
        </xfg:Gradient>
    </xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an overload of the `ContentPage`?

Create a file, for instance, `GlossContentPage`.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:xfg="clr-namespace:XFGloss;assembly=XFGloss"
         x:Class="YourApp.Pages.GlossContentPage">
    <xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
        <xfg:Gradient Rotation="170">
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#9DCC5F" StepPercentage="0" />
            <xfg:GradientStep StepColor="#00B0CD" StepPercentage="1" />
        </xfg:Gradient>
    </xfg:ContentPageGloss.BackgroundGradient>
</ContentPage>
```

Now just start using your new `GlossContentPage`, instead of a regular `ContentPage`, like:

```
<pages:GlossContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:YourApp.Pages;assembly=YourApp"
         x:Class="YourApp.Pages.MyNewShinyPage">
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</pages:GlossContentPage>
```

Comment: I have more element want to add to content page by different case, so style is once of my first choose.  Does Xamarin Form can do it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: My mean is does Xamarin forms can do it by Style define?

Comment: Since you are using a third-party component, this cannot be done through styles